# call of overloaded function is ambiguous when compiled opencv+cuda

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to compile a simple opencv+cuda c++ code but I keep getting the same error, I reinstalled opencv a few times but still getting the same error

```
cucv.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
cucv.cpp:58:47: error: call of overloaded ‘cvtColor(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, <unnamed enum>)’ is ambiguous
         cvtColor(src_host,src_host,CV_BGR2GRAY);
                                               ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/videostab/global_motion.hpp:56:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/videostab/stabilizer.hpp:50,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/videostab.hpp:78,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:101,
                 from cucv.cpp:3:
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp:90:19: note: candidate: void cv::cuda::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int, cv::cuda::Stream&)
 CV_EXPORTS_W void cvtColor(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int code, int dcn = 0, Stream& stream = Stream::Null());
                   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:74:0,
                 from cucv.cpp:3:
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/imgproc.hpp:3531:19: note: candidate: void cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int)
 CV_EXPORTS_W void cvtColor( InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int code, int dstCn = 0 )
```

Comment: Would you, by chance, have both `using namespace cv;` and `using namespace cv::cuda;` in your code?

Comment: yes, i'm gonna remove them and compile it again. Thanks for fast response

Comment: it worked but using nvcc not g++, thank you very much